# Read gray value of pixel positions from list in image (python)

Tags: python, list, image, tuples

I have a greyvalue image (8 bit) and a list "l" which contains the position of some pixels. First I want to read the grey value for each position stored in the list and then exchange this pixel with a black pixel.

My code so far:

```
img = cv2.imread(...)
list = [(11, 5), (3, 16), (0, 25), (2, 40)]


new_list_np = np.array(list)

img_np = np.array(img)

list_w_greyvalue = []

for i in new_list_np:
    list_w_greyvalue.append(img[new_list_np[i, 0], new_list_np[i, 1]])

for j in new_list_np:
    img_np = img[new_list_np[j, 0], new_list_np[j, 1]] = 0
```

The last part, with the drawing of the black pixels works, but when I want to output the list with greyvalues, I always get a list with tuples and I can't really understand the values in it.
Actually it should be a single value for each pixel, which represents the grey value, why do I get a tuple?

What also confuses me about this:
The variable j, which I use to count up through the (working) loop, also takes the form of a tuple (for my image: [ 692 1023] ). But this should also be just a number which is counted up?

Thanks already for the help (i am a beginner in coding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code. First, `list` is the name of a built-in type in Python. By using that as the name of a variable, you are overwriting that type's constructor. It's a bad thing to do. Give it a better, more descriptive name, like:

```py
>>> pixels_of_interest = [(11, 5), (3, 16), (0, 25), (2, 40)]
```

Second, you can read all the values of the image at once using advanced indexing:

```py
>>> gray_values = img_np[tuple(zip(*pixels_of_interest))]
```

To see what's going on here:

```py
>>> tuple(zip(*pixels_of_interest))
((11, 3, 0, 2), (5, 16, 25, 40))
```

The `zip(*pixels_of_interest)` essentially groups all the x- and y-coordinates into two separate tuples. Then, by using those tuples as indices, you can access the values of each of those pixels in the image array.

Lastly, now that you have your gray values, you can use that same list of coordinates to set the image array's values to zero:

```py
>>> img_np[tuple(zip(*pixels_of_interest))] = 0
```

### All together:

```py
pixels_of_interest = [(11, 5), (3, 16), (0, 25), (2, 40)]
indices_to_read = tuple(zip(*pixels_of_interest))  # make advanced index tuple
gray_values = img_np[indices_to_read]  # read gray values
img_np[indices_to_read] = 0  # overwrite with black pixel
```

### Some other issues

Another one of the issues is this:

```py
img_np = img[new_list_np[j, 0], new_list_np[j, 1]] = 0
```

You're assigning `img_np` to the value of `img[new_list_np[j, 0], new_list_np[j, 1]]` and then trying to assign *that* the value `0`. It's just plain the wrong way to modify the values of an array. All you need is `some_array[row_index, column_index] = some_value`, generally speaking. Also, `img` is the `cv2.imgread()` object, and I don't know for sure what type that object is but you almost certainly meant to use `img_np`. Same thing happens in both your `for` loops, by the way. (This is why it helps to give your variables better names, like `cv2_img_data` and `img_array` for the result from `cv2.imgread` and converting it to a numpy array.)

The thing with advanced indexing is that you can do that same reassignment for multiple coordinates at once, instead of having to iterate over your list of coordinates.

Also, the reason you're seeing tuples when you iterate is because *you're iterating through a 2D array created from your tuples:*

```py
>>> array_from_pixels = np.array(pixels_of_interest)
>>> for i in tuple_array:
...     print(i)
[11  5]
[ 3 16]
[ 0 25]
[ 2 40]
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much for your detailed help. I still have to think a little deeper into the functions, but it already works. Thanks for your help. (Edited this post, did not comment out my old pixel blackening function at first, sorry for confusion)

Comment: @StefanJ I think that depends on whether the pixel coordinates are starting at the top left or the bottom left, i.e., what is the x-y coordinate of the top left most pixel in the image? How does cv2 read the image data?